# TabBarController and SplitViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

i want my `splitviewController` to be displayed in within a `TabBarController`. Unfortunately, I firstly decided to just have a `SplitViewController` and chose apple's template. Now i am in the inconvenient position not knowing how to add it to a tab bar.

I tried several stuff that was explained here on StackOverflow but the best result was a black screen with a tab bar below it :-(

I am just struggling to find a nice and simple way.

Code of my `Appdelegate`:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{
// Override point for customization after application launch.
// Add the split view controller's view to the window and display.
self.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

NSArray *searchPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
documentFolderPath = [searchPaths objectAtIndex: 0];
self.rootViewController.directoryPath = documentFolderPath; 

NSURL *docUrl = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey];
if ([docUrl isFileURL]) {
    NSString *path = [docUrl path];
    self.detailViewController.currentFilePath = path;
    [self.detailViewController setDetails:path newFile:FALSE];
}
return YES;
```

Comment: so you want one of the tabs of your UITabBarController to show a UISplitViewController, with two views in it?

Comment: Check at my answer, also you can use Interface Builder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Apple's documentation this is a no no situation.

But there is a way to achieve this easily (we did it for an application).

have a look at http://www.codeworth.com/blog/mobile/ios-splitviewcontroller-inside-tabviewcontroller/

I think this would be the apt answer for the question.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot! Can I still use the popover isntead of the left view in the `splitviewcontroller's` portrait mode?

Comment: Of-course we can. But,we should be little tricky for that. i have an idea i will try and come back to you.

Comment: I managed to hide Root view in potrait mode but the navigation controllers back button is occupying the top left corner & hence it seems to be little complex one.

Comment: Elvis's answer is also an apt one. but the IntelligentSplitViewController also doesn't seems to have popover for left view

Comment: You think it would be possible to realise the whole thing with storyboards?

Comment: This answer is IMO wrong. You should not do: `[self.view addsubView:leftVc.view];` You are creating inconsistent hierarchy (Views vs. ViewControllers). See WWDC session 102 from 2011 where they explain why it is wrong. For example orientation change will not work correctly

Comment: OK, Ondra Peterka you may be right. But the thing is that the tabcontroller itself manages to change orientation depending on the the shouldAutoRotate method of all its child view controllers. so returning proper value should be fine.

Comment: SplitViewController inside a TabBarController isn't a 'no no' anymore. Check out Apple's Podcasts app on the iPad.

Answer (score 6):

You should check [IntelligentSplitViewController](https://github.com/grgcombs/IntelligentSplitViewController) is everything you need!

Adding some controllers and design you can end with something like this:

[image: Screenshot of an iPad app using IntelligentSplitViewController]

**PS**: I've actually have an app in the App Store using this controller so go head!

Answer (score 5):

Edit:

i just realized you actually wanted a splitview inside the tabbar.  per apple documentation, this is a no no.  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/iPadControllers/iPadControllers.html

> A split view controller must always be the root of any interface you
>   create. In other words, you must always install the view from
>   aUISplitViewController object as the root view of your application’s
>   window. The panes of your split-view interface may then contain
>   navigation controllers, tab bar controllers, or any other type of view
>   controller you need to implement your interface.

---

If you still want to use a tabbar the stuff i wrote below still applies, but your subview should not be a splitview controller.

**original answer:**

you'd create the tabbar controller in the code, then add the splitview controller as one of the tabs.  in your case, self.splitViewController will become one of the view controllers inside your tabbar controller.  I haven't tried this using an apple template app as a starting point, but give it should work.

you can look for tutorials on uitabbarcontroller for more information.  This one looks promising: http://www.xcode-tutorials.com/uitabbarcontroller-and-uinavigationcontroller/

And this is handy too: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

heres a sample:

```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
        //set tbconroller as root view controller of window
        [self.window setRootViewController:tabBarController];
        //window retains controller so we can release
        [tabBarController release];

        //create two view controllers
        UIViewController *vc1 = [[HypnosisViewController alloc] init];
        UIViewController *vc2 = [[CurrentTimeViewController alloc] init];
        //make an array containing these two view controllers
        NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:vc1,vc2,nil];

        [tabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllers];

        //the views are retained their new owners, so we can release
        [vc1 release];
        [vc2 release];          

        [[self window] makeKeyAndVisible];
        return YES;
    }
```

if you're using interface builder, here are a few more tutorials http://www.cimgf.com/2009/06/25/uitabbarcontroller-with-uinavigationcontroller-using-interface-builder/   or http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/iphone-tabbar-uitabbarcontroller-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks mate! You used Hillegass's example code, right ;) I was wondering whether was a way to do it completely in IB, with storyboards and stuff?

Comment: good eye! :)  i enjoyed the book and still had some sample code from it floating around.  i dont think there is a way in IB because apple doesnt want us to.

Comment: SplitViewController inside a TabBarController isn't a 'no no' anymore. Check out Apple's Podcasts app on the iPad.

Answer (score 3):

I just solved this issue as it has been running in my head background for the last couple of days.
You can have as many "Split view" as you want inside a "UITabbarView" or vars versa, without using any code, but if you want to satisfy Apple and make the Split view controller is the root controller, you have to type one line of code.

So the beef is here.

1. Create one single view project, or what ever you like.
2. In the Main Storyboard drag and drop split view controller.
3. Drag the initialising arrow from the "single view controller" and
   appoint it to the your "split view Controller".
4. Now if you run your    project you it should loads the split view.
5. Create new coca touch file subclass of "UISplitViewController", call
   it whatever you like.
6. In "viewDidLoad" add the following line "self.preferredDisplayMode =
   .PrimaryHidden" // just to hide the master view
7. Back you the Main storyboard select the Split view controller and
       make it's view controller the one you just created.
8. Now, delete the "View" of the details view controller (just the
   view)
9. Find the "Container view" in the objects library, drag it and drop
   it in the details view controller.
10. This will generates view controller connected to the "Container
     View" Embed the generated view controller in "Tab Bar Controller"
     Now, you have Split View connected to Tab Bar controller.
11. Your TabBarController should have one view controller (item 1),
         replace the the "view" (only view) of the this controller with
         "ContainerView".
12. Now drag and drop new Split view controller from the "Objects
     library" Connect the "ContainerView" in "Item 1" to the new added
     "Split view controller".
13. Now, if you recall we should have one view controller hanging
     somewhere around, as we created single view project, find that
     controller connect it to the the tab bar controller, so now you
     have 2 items.
14. Repeat the same process, replace the view with "container view" and
         add new split view controller and connect it to this story boards.

Now, this final Storyboard should looks something like this. Again you don't have to start from Split view controller, but I did this just to match Apple recommendation.

### [image]

[image]